# Enabling Borderless Windowed Mode

Tags: blueprint-tycoon

Is it possible to launch Blueprint Tycoon in a borderless window? I'd like to have it running in the background while I do some other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that this game is built in Unity. As a result of this the standard Unity commands work perfectly. To enable this I did the following:

1. Start the game normally
2. Click Options -> Video
3. Check that the fullscreen option is disabled (should look grey)
4. Apply the settings change if needed and exit the game
5. In your Steam library select the game
6. Rightclick on it and select Properties
7. On the General tab click "Set Launch Options"
8. In the box that appears type `-popupwindow` and hit OK and then Close on the properties window
9. Launch the game as normal, it will now be in a borderless window

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party applications such as [Borderless Gaming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/borderless-gaming.mirror/) for this purpose.